# What is GlyphCache type in a function to render text in Piston2d

Tags: rust, rust-piston

I am trying to write a separate function to render text using piston2d. Taking the [hello_world.rs](https://github.com/PistonDevelopers/piston-examples/blob/master/src/hello_world.rs) example, I am trying to extend that to allow me to render text from within a function.

Here is the code that I wrote:

```
extern crate piston_window;
extern crate find_folder;

use piston_window::*;

fn main() {
    let mut window: PistonWindow = WindowSettings::new(
            "piston: try to render text",
            [200, 200]
        )
        .exit_on_esc(true)
        .build()
        .unwrap();

    let assets = find_folder::Search::ParentsThenKids(3, 3)
        .for_folder("assets").unwrap();
    println!("{:?}", assets);
    let ref font = assets.join("FiraSans-Regular.ttf");
    let factory = window.factory.clone();
    let mut glyphs = Glyphs::new(font, factory, TextureSettings::new()).unwrap();

    window.set_lazy(true);
    while let Some(e) = window.next() {
        window.draw_2d(&e, |c, mut g| {
            clear([0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0], g);
            render_text(10.0, 100.0, "Hello World", 32, c, &mut g, &mut glyphs);
        });
    }
}

fn render_text(x: f64, y: f64,
               text: &str, size: u32,
               c: Context, g: &mut G2d, 
               glyphs: &mut glyph_cache::rusttype::GlyphCache<GfxFactory, G2dTexture>) {
    text::Text::new(size).draw(
           text,
           &mut glyphs,
           &c.draw_state,
           c.transform.trans(x, y),
           g
        ).unwrap();
}
```

When I try to run this code, I get the following error:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `&mut piston_window::glyph_cache::rusttype::GlyphCache<'_, gfx_device_gl::factory::Factory, piston_window::Texture<gfx_device_gl::Resources>>: piston_window::character::CharacterCache` is not satisfied

the trait `piston_window::character::CharacterCache` is not implemented for `&mut piston_window::glyph_cache::rusttype::GlyphCache<'_, gfx_device_gl::factory::Factory, piston_window::Texture<gfx_device_gl::Resources>>`
```

I have tried many different types for `glyphs`, and this was the farthest I could get.

What should the type be?
Any guidance is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are passing a mutable reference to a mutable reference to the `GlyphCache` to [`draw()`](https://docs.rs/piston2d-graphics/0.26.0/graphics/text/struct.Text.html#method.draw) (`render_text` receives a mutable reference, and you then create a mutable reference to *that*). Simply change `&mut glyphs` to `glyphs` in the call to `draw()`.

`draw()` expects a mutable reference to a type that implements `Graphics<Texture = <C as CharacterCache>::Texture>`, and `GlyphCache<GfxFactory, G2dTexture>` does implement that trait, but `&mut GlyphCache<GfxFactory, G2dTexture>` doesn't.

When the type of a function parameter is a concrete type, the compiler will automatically dereference a reference to match the expected type ([Clippy](https://github.com/rust-lang-nursery/rust-clippy) has a lint to identify the places where unnecessary references are created). However, when the type of the function paramter is a generic type (as is the case here), the compiler will not try to do that.